# Is this a valid way to factorize polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So in the examples of my math textbook there is the problem of factoring polynomials:

> Factor $-3x^2 -2xy +8y^2 +11x -8y -6$

And the way they solved it is as follows:

**Solution**: 
If we only take terms with $x$ and constants we get $-3x^2 + 11x - 6$ 
$-3x^2 + 11x - 6  \equiv (-3x +2)(x-3)$ or $(3x - 2)(-x +3) ......(1)$

If we only take terms with $y$ and constants we get $8y^2 - 8y - 6$ 
$8y^2 - 8y - 6 \equiv (4y + 2)(2y -3)$ or $(-4y - 2)(-2y +3) ......(2)$

We will get the factors of the given polynomial if we combine the factors of $(1)$ and $(2)$ , but the constants $+2,-3$ or $-2,+3$ have to be the same in both equation just like the coefficient of $x$ and $y$.

$\therefore$ The factors are $(-3x + 4y + 2)(x +2y -3)$ or $(3x - 4y -2)(-x -2y +3)$

We can test if the calculated factors are valid by matching the coefficient of $xy$ 
 $-3.2 + 4.1 = -2$ or $3.(-2) - 4.(-1) = -2$. (QED)

I have read it many times but still couldn't get how this method even works.So I have some questions: 
(1) Is this a valid way to factorize polynomials ? 
(2) Is there any reference where this method is used ?

Comment: It is only a heuristic --- there is no guarantee (in particular, this method misses the coefficient of $xy$, along with many other shortcomings) hence the check at the end is absolutely necessary.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283802/factoring-3x2-2xy-8y2-11x-8y-6

Comment: @Sharkos Yes , And I feel like an year of dizziness just washed away.Kind of wish the book explained it more thoroughly.